# how to show table on asp.net(c#) when select id from table where color='blue'

Tags: c#, sql, string, select, connection-string

I can't show my Table on asp.net's Grid-view when my SQL string with the string of the condition

I have **color which type is varchar(4)**
in my SQL string connection, it cant work on my code
I can't see the table when color in my code
wrong part=>**color'"+blue+"'** 
it doesn't work

```
 protected void BindData()
    {     
        DataSet ds;
        string SQL = "";




        SQL = ("select  id from table where color='"+blue+"'");
        ds = CreateDataSource(string.Format("exec P_PageData '{0}',{1},{2}", SQL, this.SplitPage1.CurrentPage, this.SplitPage1.PageSize));
        if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count == 3)
        {
            this.SplitPage1.CurrentPage = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["CurPage"]);
            this.SplitPage1.TotalRecorder = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["Total"]);
            this.rptPremissionList.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];
            this.rptPremissionList.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

It doesn't work if blur(string) is in code
if I replace it with others `INT column`
it can work
please help me how to fix it if it's a string of condition

Comment: It can't work if replace string column

Answer (score 0):

SQL = "select o.DEPTNM as NM,count(distinct p.id) as A,cast(count(p.id) AS FLOAT)/nullif( count(o.id),0) as B,count(distinct case when o.color='" +blue+ "' then p.id end) as C from table1 as o left join table2 as p on p.id=o.idgroup by o.DEPTNM";

The string needs to be wrapped in single quotes.

That said, if you used a parameterised query, you wouldn't be having this problem.